# Display google chart on scrollTop()

Tags: jquery, charts

I am trying to trigger google chart drawing on a specific event. In these case it will be scrollTop position (I think it's the best solution here).

but I don't know what should I do with "setOnLoadCallback", I think this function causes me so much trouble.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization2);
    } else {
        //....
    }


});
```

Of course I can make a workaround here, and draw charts, make them invisible and then display them by adding a class in ex. ".make-visible" when user will be able to view them, but the main purpose I am trying to combine these two is that I don't want to load everything on page load cause it's not necessary, I want to load it when it needed.

Here's my codepen code with charts. Thanks in advance for any help.
http://codepen.io/Nikolaus91/pen/NPmzLw

Funny thing, when launched Chrome's "Inspect element" on my codpen I can see: Jquery is not defined error. Well... it should be specified, cause I did add it to may codepen in JS settings.

I don't get it.

Comment: another issue with google charts, when implemented charts on my wordpress site I received error: "Container is not defined". It is defined and chart rendering works well on codepen, why it's not on wordpress?

Charts are rendered on my Wordpress page but with wrong size, they are very small

Comment: Found solution, on wordpress you need to specify div size directly in api options, otherwise you will render ultra small  and unreadable chart

Comment: But I am still getting this weird error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems hard coded, however, it works.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: callback });

function callback() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(window).scrollTop() >= 200 ) {        
                drawVisualization1();      
      }  
    });
};
```

BTW, don't forget to lint your code.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/agriboz/pen/ragjrN)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do callback too, but you were first, works great :)

Comment: Works great on codepen but on WP it's not, do you have an idea what might be causing this? It should be workin in section 2, I ahve an error conatiner is not defined, but it is defined...
http://hsc.center/why-us/ PASS: hsc.center